# What is the mistake in this AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my Ajax call to `htmlpage1.html` file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#html").load("htmlpage1.html", function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

My htmlpage1.html contains code:

```
<body>
    <div id="div2">Hi</div>
</body>
```

On the end of the call i am getting an empty alert box. I have to get "Hi" as output. what is the mistake am I doing?

Comment: What about closing body tag in htmlpage1.html ?

Comment: "#html" is a div in the page where the script is called.

Comment: check your browser console... is there any error

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: [Explain me about Jquery-Ajax calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046875/explain-me-about-jquery-ajax-calls)

Comment: @Quentin Yes,but that question was not asked clear. i deleted that question already.

Comment: @arun p johny I am getting output in IE but not in Chrome. what may be the problem.

Comment: @sms — Then edit it, don't duplicate it.

Comment: @sms — Since you deleted the other question, along with all the helpful comments people made on it, I'm not all that motivated to try to answer your duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin the only comment in that question was providing to a link. it is to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/... anyways sorry for deleting it.

Comment: try http://plnkr.co/edit/bpmh0DBVhjAOXRtsrEjN?p=preview

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you. your code too works fine in IE but not in Chrome.

Comment: @sms I'm testing in chrome... it seems fine.... anyway can you remove the `body` tag from the requested page and test again

Comment: @ArunPJohny still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the script to

```
             $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#html").load("htmlpage1.html", function (data) {
                console.log(data);


            });
        });
```

Now it is working fine in all browsers. I think the problem is with the button click. Each browser is taking the button click in different manner. If anybody know to solve the issue please suggest your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check like this
If you are using Chrome, 
press F12. A DevTools window will appear, click on the Network Panel. Now click the button. 

Network Panel will show the ajax call in it. 
In your case, under name/Path in right-bottom side of panel, there will be page named "htmlpage1.html". 
Click on it. On the right side of panel click in the Response or Preview. 
The response will be shown there.
```

Refer for details https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: yes i tried.it is showing as get method and status as canceled.

Comment: and when i replace alert box with console.log(data) i am getting output in IE still not in chrome. and now htmlpage1.html is not at all coming in network panel.

Comment: many be some kind of Browser compatibility issues. htmlpage1.html not listed means the call is not made. Please create a file in http://plnkr.co/. so that it will be easy for check.